# How can I expose constant values in MVEL?

Tags: java, reflection, scripting, mvel

I have a constant that I want to import/expose to [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) expressions:

```
public static final String PRODUCT_NAME;
```

I know I can import classes, packages and static methods using [addImport](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Programmatic+Imports+for+2.0), but there is no support for constants.

I have looked at writing a [custom VariableResolver](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Custom+Variable+Resolvers) but it looks like overkill. Is there an easier way to do this?

[Edit] To be clear, I want to be able to do this in my expressions:

```
"Thanks for using " + PRODUCT_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly reference it using the fully qualified name: `org.foo.Bar.PRODUCT_NAME`

-or-

You can use programmatic imports using the MVEL compiler:

```
ParserContext ctx = ParserContext.create();
ctx.addImport(YourClass.class);

String expr = "YourClass.PRODUCT_NAME";
Serializable compiled = MVEL.compileExpreasion(expr, ctx);
Object result = MVEL.executeExpression(compiled);
```

Comment: I know I can make a class available, but how about just the constant? PRODUCT_NAME?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MVEL, but if you say you can import static methods, then you should be able to do this instead:

```
public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "My cool product";
public static final String getProductName() {
   return PRODUCT_NAME;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I'd like to be able to expose the constant itself (since that is what the users will be writing in their scripts), not a getter method.

Answer (score -1):

I am very new to MVEL myself. But I think this should work.

I may have misunderstood your quedtion. I am assuming you are looking for a way to access constants.

*Java side declaration:*

```
public class Product{
   public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "TEST";
}
```

*In the rules file:-*

```
import org.sample.Product;

rule "Test"
    no-loop true
    lock-on-active true
    when
       eval(true);
    then
        System.out.println(Product.PRODUCT_NAME); #prints TEST

  end
```

Comment: What's a rules file? I've never seen those before? Is this some special DSL I need to use?

Comment: @Frederik - Drools uses MVEL so thats why I mentioned it.